# MADV_DONTNEED on shared anonymous memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmap

I'd like to reclaim pages for the memory region mapped by mmap(MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS).

For this purpose, I called madvise(MADV_DONTNEED) for this shared memory from all the processes that can see this shared region.

However, the physical pages for this shared region cannot be freed and the shared data remains on the shared memory.

How can you completely reclaim pages for the memory region mapped by mmap(MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS)?

Comment: Are you trying to partially unmap pages from an `mmap`ed region? As far as I can tell you're allowed to call `munmap` on part of a mapped region (with page alignment/size).

Comment: I'd like to reclaim the shared pages without unmapping the mapped region (without destructing vm_area_sturct instance). After all, is munmap is the only way to free and reclaim the shared pages?

Comment: Does the resident set size (RSS) of the processes get reduced?

Comment: Yes. Just after calling MADV_DONTNEED, the process's RSS reduces.

Comment: Well if RSS goes down, then how come you say "the physical pages for this shared region cannot be freed"? What other metric do you use to deduce this?

Comment: As I said in the first question, because "the shared data remains on the shared memory".

Even after calling MADV_DONTNEED from every  process that can see the shared memory, the data contained on the shared area is not destroyed, which means the shared physical memory is not reclaimed by the linux kernel.

Comment: Just came back here randomly today. But... what you observe seems normal to me. Unless you `munmap` the region, data will always be available. The manual page for `madvise` specifically says that reading memory after a successful `MADV_DONTNEED` will re-populate the pages. Am I missing something? Also, maybe consider adding a simple [mre] of a program that does what you observe.